# Avoid parsing xml fields in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, architecture, devexpress

I use XAF(DevExpress framework) for my first application (it's a CMS). There is a Scheduler component.
And, it saves recurrence of event like xml. For example:

```
<RecurrenceInfo Start="02/21/2012 09:00:00" End="02/28/2012 11:30:00" Id="e8507496-2be9-4bde-90a6-9eeea98fdc5a" Range="2" />
```

This is Range enum(but there are some other enum exist):

```
public enum RecurrenceRange {
        NoEndDate,
        OccurrenceCount,
        EndByDate
    }
```

Also, I have another application (ASP.NET MVC). I need select event for specific date or period(today, tomorrow, current month and other).

The pproblem in that in a table will be 10000(for example) records then I need to parse all of them to find event for request date. I think this is reduce perfomance.

What solution do you see?

I think to do the following: when event is created (in CMS) then add some persistent fields in the table and programmaticaly fill them.

How it is better to create fields for storage of this data?

And one more question.
For example, Event will go in a current of week at 5 o'clock and at 8 o'clock. The scheduler will create two records in the table:

```
id      EventName      RecurrenceInfo      Description        //otherfields
1        event1            xml1            description1
2        event1            xml2            description1
```

The problem in that the Scheduler  create one more records and all fields equals except RecurrenceInfo.
I think to create one more id column and assign the same value all duplicate records.

Thanks and sorry my english.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a [Xml typed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and use the folowing query

```
select
  (list of fields)
from
  MyTable
where
  MyXmlField.value('(/root[Start])', 'datetime') > '01.01.2001'
```

Comment: The type of RecurrenceInfo field is nvarchar and I can't change it.

Comment: you can add drigger, and put xml to your another table with XML column there, or parse XML and put to table with Start End datetime columns